# Draw a line on canvas with custom style (delphi)

Tags: delphi, styles, line

I need draw some lines on a canvas, however I need use a custom style, no standart style as solid, dot, ...

For example I need draw a line as "__ . __ . _*" or "* . _ . _ . _ . _". All my line are a mix of dash and dot and I need set also dash lenght and dash, dot width.

I don't want use GDI+ or other external library...

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: ExtCreatePen function allows to create user style pen (with some limitations)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the size of a dash of a line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123667/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-a-dash-of-a-line)

Comment: Thumbs down to whoever voted to close this...

Comment: @Jerry - The vote is mine, the reason is that the question is an exact duplicate, also the answer is. Follow the link...

Comment: I would call partial duplicate, not exact. The prior question is asking to "change the size of the dashes" whereas this one is "how to do a custom style line" - although the methods to accomplish both are the same, the end goal of each is different.

Comment: @Jerry - You can't change the size of the dashes without customizing line style, these questions are identical. Although obviously we disagree on that.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with plain GDI:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  pattern: array[0..3] of cardinal = (10, 1, 1, 1);
var
  lb: TLogBrush;
  pen, oldpen: HPEN;
begin
  lb.lbStyle := BS_SOLID;
  lb.lbColor := RGB(255, 0, 0);
  pen := ExtCreatePen(PS_COSMETIC or PS_USERSTYLE, 1, lb, length(pattern), @pattern);
  if pen <> 0 then
    try
      oldpen := SelectObject(Canvas.Handle, pen);
      Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
      Canvas.LineTo(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
      SelectObject(Canvas.Handle, oldpen);
    finally
      DeleteObject(pen);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Why I cannot change width parameter? If I change it I get always a solid line with width = 1...

Comment: @Martin: I think GDI cosmetic pens can only have unit width. [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162705(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: if I change "pattern: array[0..3] of cardinal" into "pattern: array of cardinal" and then use "SetLength(pattern, 4);" and set the array value with 10, 1, 1 and 1 I get always a continues line. Why? Is there a way to set array length and change the value before create the new pen?

Comment: @Martin: Because dynamic arrays are pointers, and so are not stored 'in-place' in memory. Hence, you have to replace `@pattern` by `@pattern[0]` if you use dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [LineDDA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd145025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. Sure the Pen styling (as adviced by Andreas Rejbrand) is much faster, but LineDDA will allow you to draw the parts of the line in different colors.

```
var
  DottedLineDrawCounter: Integer;

procedure DDAProc(AX, AY: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas); stdcall;
begin
  if DottedLineDrawCounter mod 4 = 0 then
    ACanvas.Pixels[AX, AY] := clRed
  else
    ACanvas.Pixels[AX, AY] := clBlack;
  Inc(DottedLineDrawCounter);
end;

...
begin
  // Usage
  DottedLineDrawCounter := 0;
  LineDDA(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, @DDAProc, LPARAM(Canvas));
end;
```